# Why so few complex multiplication

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves

Let's take I lattice $\Lambda$ and $\alpha\in\Lambda$. Then we have $\alpha\Lambda\subseteq\Lambda$ so $z\mapsto \alpha z$ induces an isogenie $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda\to\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ wich has no reason to be one $[n]:\overline{z}\mapsto \overline{nz}$.

What's wrong? Normally They are very few lattice $\Lambda$ for which there exist a complex multiplication on $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$.

Comment: The lattice is not closed under multiplication  general!

Comment: (Usually when one gets to a point where one has to ask «What's wrong?», the correct approach is to concientiously check all the claims one has made to get there. In you case, you made exactly one such claim: one that $\Lambda$ is closed under multiplication. You should scrutinize it!)

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez  Thanks for your first comment! For the second... it's a time problem. When we are not student and with family such a thing can take one or two days. And in the forum it's ovious for someone. Yes, but you can say it's interessant on it's own, but if I says that for everythings I would never really progress...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice, generated by $w_1$ and $w_2$. Then,
$$\Lambda = \{aw_1+bw_2 : a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$
If $\alpha\in\Lambda$ there is no reason, in general, to expect that $\alpha\Lambda \subseteq \Lambda$. In other words, $\alpha w_1$ and/or $\alpha w_2$ may not be elements of $\Lambda$.

Since $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda \cong \mathbb{C}/\lambda\Lambda$, we may assume $\Lambda = \langle 1,\tau\rangle$ for some $\tau\in\mathbb{C}$ (note $\tau\not\in \mathbb{R}$, otherwise $\Lambda$ would not be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$). Now, let $\alpha\in \Lambda$ such that $\alpha \Lambda \subseteq \Lambda$. Since $\alpha\in\Lambda$, we have $\alpha=a+b\tau$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. And since $\alpha \Lambda \subseteq \Lambda$, we must have $\alpha\tau = c+d\tau$ for some $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$. Putting this together we obtain
$$(a+b\tau)\tau = c+d\tau,$$
or,  $b\tau^2+(a-d)\tau -c = 0$. In other words, $\tau$ satisfies a quadratic equation with integer coefficients, and therefore $\mathbb{Q}(\tau)$ is an imaginary quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. But most lattices $\Lambda=\langle 1,\tau\rangle$ do not satisfy this hypothesis, as $\tau$ would be arbitrary (for instance, the elements $\tau\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\tau)/\mathbb{Q}$ is quadratic is countable, while its complement in  $\mathbb{C}$ is not).